# Xcode 4.3 getting freeze at startup

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.3

I have installed Xcode 4.3 version. I can't click on any button of the Xcode bar, because Xcode freeze at startup, and if i move the cursor on the bar, i have only the loading cursor available. So i can't click on Window Tab to restore the Welcome Window, and i can't open a new project.

It seems that Xcode is not loading any project, and maybe it is the problem it has not found any project, and it continues to search anyway. If I try to launch an existing project, Xcode tries to open it, but the result is always the blank window with "No Editor".

Please help me to come out from this issue or any one please tell me how can I remove all the logs, settings and back up files of Xcode

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What OS version and what *exact* version of Xcode ?

Comment: Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3 (11D2001) and Xcode 4.3.3

Comment: Any non-standard/third-party extensions ?

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand your question :(

Comment: Have you installed any third party software which operates at a system level ? Also what kind of Mac are you using ?

Comment: I am using softwares like Google Chrome, Firefox and LibreOffice only and i am having Mac Mini

Comment: OK - try running Disk Utility and fix any problems with your file system and permissions.

Comment: Disk utility didn't found any problems. Now also Xcode being in the same state :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem :) Simply download and install the latest version of iTunes, it's fixed :) Now i can work with Xcode. I dont know whats the connection between Xcode and iTunes. Cheers....